# How can I model 2 different relationships between the same objects in Laravel 5's Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Edit 4**: Problem solved. The issue arising in edit 3 was only a data error.

Final answer: specifying foreign keys in the belongstomany relationships and clearing my PHP cache afterwards.

---

**Edit 3**: I've made the queries come out differently by specifying a foreign key in the belongsToMany relationship. However the query still doesn't return the results I need. Here is the generated query:

```
select `streams`.*, `followers`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `followers`.`stream_id` as `pivot_stream_id` from `streams` inner join `followers` on `streams`.`id` = `followers`.`stream_id` where `followers`.`user_id` =
```

---

**Edit 2**: The root problem is that User::following() and Stream::followers() are generating the exact same query despite being different sides of a many to many relationship.

---

**Edit**: I captured the query coming from User::following() and it looks like it's basing the query on a stream_id rather than the user_id, I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
select `users`.*, `followers`.`stream_id` as `pivot_stream_id`, `followers`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` from `users` inner join `followers` on `users`.`id` = `followers`.`user_id` where `followers`.`stream_id` = ?
```

---

I have a **Users** table, and A **Streams** table.

Each **User** has many **Streams**

Each **Stream** also has many **Users**(followers) in addition to the one **User** that owns it.

How Do I correctly set up this functionality in Eloquent? Right now I have a belongsToMany relationship in both models, setting up a many-to-many relationship on a pivot table. However this seems to conflict with the hasMany relationship in the **User** model and the belongsTo relationship in the **Streams** model that use the foreign key user_id on the **Streams** table.

To clarify, the final functionality I'm expecting is that a **User** object can return both a list of the **Stream** objects it owns, and the **Stream** objects it is following. A **Stream** object should be able to return both the one **User** object that owns it, and the multiple **User** objects that follow it.

However, right now, when I try to obtain a list of the streams a user is following, using the User::following() method, it returns the same results as the User::streams() method.

Here are how the tables are currently laid out:

**Users**

```
| id | name | email | password | token | created_at | updated_at |
|----|------|-------|----------|-------|------------|------------|
```

**Streams**

```
| id | name | user_id | created_at | updated_at |
|----|------|---------|------------|------------|
```

**Pivot "followers"**

```
| id | stream_id | user_id | created_at | updated_at |
|----|-----------|---------|------------|------------|
```

And here are the two model classes:

**Stream**

```
class Stream extends Model {

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function followers() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers');
    }

}
```

**User**

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'token'];

    public function streams() {
        return $this->hasMany(Stream::class);
    }

    public function following() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Stream::class, 'followers');
    }

}
```

Comment: Your setup looks right. Can u dump the `DB::getQueryLog();` after you retrieve the relationships and post the output?

Comment: DB::getQueryLog(); is empty if I dump it after I retrieve relationships in the controller. Is there somewhere else I should use it?

Comment: `User::first()->streams()->get(); User::first()->following()->get(); dd(DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: Those two statements don't actually do anything. I'm pretty sure that's invalid syntax for Eloquent.

Comment: I used an Event listener to capture the queries. Here's the query for User::following() - `select \`users\`.*, \`followers\`.\`stream_id\` as \`pivot_stream_id\`, \`followers\`.\`user_id\` as \`pivot_user_id\` from \`users\` inner join \`followers\` on \`users\`.\`id\` = \`followers\`.\`user_id\` where \`followers\`.\`stream_id\` = ?` And here's the query for User::streams() - `select * from \`streams\` where \`streams\`.\`user_id\` = ? and \`streams\`.\`user_id\` is not null`

Comment: You should self-answer this question, rather than edit the question to include an answer.